# Twitter API - What to store on app side?

Tags: php, twitter

So I want people to be able to login to the site via Twitter. For facebook I store the facebook id and the access token. In twitter from what I gather I need to store the twitter id, access token and secret token? Is that correct if I want to do things such as post to a twitter feed? Im using the twitter php sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you only need the access token and the secret token (the twitter id is not required).

Actually, now that I think about it, since you are using Twitter for login, the Twitter id would be required too (for login purposes, not posting to Twitter).

See: [Twitter API - Making a resource request on a user's behalf](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#Making_a_resource_request_on_a_user-s_behalf)